# %windir% not recognized error

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to run the command `%windir%` in a  command prompt, but I am getting an below error:

[image]

Comment: Short answer: `%windir%` isn't a command. Its just a Windows built-in environment variable. `%windir%` contains the path where your Windows directory resides in. Likewise, `%homedrive%` contains the drive that windows is installed in.

Comment: The real question is: _Why_ were you trying to 'run `%windir%`? What did you think would happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strangely enough, no one has explained the entire story, i.e. the error.

Indeed `%windir%` is an variable, and its contents on your system are `C:\Windows`.
So when you 'execute' `%windir%` its contents are substituted and your command is `C:\Windows`, which, as Windows informs you is *not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*.

A fun experiment would be to place an executable named `windows.exe` in your `C:\` root ;-)

Comment: For the fun experiment (which works as expected) +1

Comment: windows.com, windows.vbs, windows.bat... also works

Answer (score 23):

`%windir%` is a variable and should be used in conjunction with standard commands or actions.

For example `CD %WINDIR%` will take you to the windows directory...

Answer (score 4):

You must be used to a different shell (in particular 4DOS/4NT/TakeCommand) where a directory name is treated as a command to change to that directory.  That’s not the case with CMD, and you have to use `CD` before it (if it is already on the same drive. I don’t know if CMD has  `cdd` command to change drive and directory).

Comment: no `cdd`, just add `/d`

Answer (score 0):

when you do `%windir%` you are meant to use it with other commands with it. so that is why there is an error. for example if you do `cd %windir%`, you will not get an error